# Building/installing Android Wear AOSP

Tags: android, wear-os

I've previously modified/built/flashed the Lollipop AOSP for a Nexus 5 but now I want to modify/build/flash the Android Wear AOSP for an LG watch but have no idea where to begin - I can find no instructions online nor in the Android Wear AOSP source about how to do this.

If its the same process as building a phone AOSP then there are still multiple unanswered questions such as:

- After downloading the Android Wear AOSP source and then typing "lunch" doesn't list any additional/different configurations. The lunch menu lists the same things for the Android Wear AOSP as it does for a standard AOSP, so how can the Wear AOSP be built?
- Are drivers for different watches necessary to be downloaded to include in the build process?
- Can a wearable device be flashed using fastboot flash XYZ.img just as a phone can?
- Are system images available for download for wearables?

I'm confused why Google have released an Android Wear AOSP if there doesn't appear to be any instructions or means of actually doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Android Wear AOSP distribution at the moment. Android Wear is currently a closed platform.

Comment: Thank you, but then I don't understand why there is an AOSP android-wear-5.0.0_r1 tag and postings like this and the links within it: http://www.androidcentral.com/android-wear-source-code-uploaded-aosp. Isn't that an Android Wear AOSP distribution? If not then what is it?

Comment: This is a misleading title. This is just Android Open Source Project release on which Android Wear is based, not the Android Wear itself

Comment: @gruszczy Any update on whether google has released the source code for Wear OS a.k.a Android Wear?

Answer (score 0):

For downloading source code:

```
mkdir ~/bin
PATH=~/bin:$PATH

curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

mkdir "WearOS"
cd "WearOS"

repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-wear-9.0.0_r11

repo sync
```

Before downloading, configure your git.

Clean up the fresh build:

```
make clobber
```

For building source code:

```
source build/envsetup.sh

lunch aosp_arm-eng

m
```

If you need device configuration:

```
lunch
```

Follow the Documentation for [Download](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading) and [Build](https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.